# Different routing behaviour between MVC2 and MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 2 app to MVC 4 and this route that I had in the MVC2 app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"RenderContentPage",                          // Route name
"{*url}",                                      // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
```

Doesn't have the same behaviour in MVC 4.

I want `/s` in the url to be kept with the url parameter, so a url like `www.mydomain.com/a/b/c` in MVC2 would be covered by the route above but in MVC4 it doesn't match.

Is there a different way in MVC4 for `/s` to be matched to a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, they do work in the same way in MVC4.

Because breakpoints dont seem to get met for requests after the intial page load i jumped to the wrong conclusion.